# ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 308 failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, deployment

I have developed a Next.js 13 project. The project is functioning properly when tested locally. However, upon deployment, the dynamic router page fails to work and produces a ChunkLoadError. The error message in the browser console is as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ofa6.png)

When we build the project locally, the dynamic router file is created successfully at the below path.
`.next\static\chunks\app\blog\[slug]\not-found-7bc1166a42ac068d.js`
However, when the project is deployed on the server, this file is generated during the build process, however we can't find this file.

I am using an AWS server.

If anyone can provide a solution for this issue, I would greatly appreciate the guidance.

This is the source codes

src/components/posts/post-card.tsx
'use client';

```
import Image from 'next/image'; import Link from 'next/link';

import CategoryList from '@/components/category-list';
import { Post } from '@/types/post';

export default function PostCard({
    post: {
        slug,
        title,
        date,
        cover,
        categories
    }
}: { 
    post: Post;
}) {  
 return (
    <Link href={`/blog/${slug}`} as={`/blog/${slug}`}>
      <article className="mx-auto flex max-w-[25rem] flex-col overflow-hidden rounded-xl shadow-xl shadow-gray-400 transition-all duration-300 hover:scale-[1.05] hover:shadow-2xl">
        <div className="relative h-60">
          <Image
            src={cover}
            alt="cover image"
            fill
            sizes="100%"
            style={{ objectFit: 'cover' }}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex h-48 flex-col p-4 text-black">
          <h3 className="line-clamp-2 h-16 text-2xl font-bold">{title}</h3>
          <time className="mb-4 mt-2 pl-2 text-sm text-gray-400">{date}</time>
          <CategoryList categories={categories} />
        </div>
      </article>
    </Link>
 );
}
```

/src/app/blog/[slug]/page.tsx

```
import { Metadata } from 'next';
import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation';

import NotionPage from '@/components/notion-page';
import RelatedPosts from '@/components/posts/related-posts';
import { getRecordMap } from '@/libs/notion';
import { getAllPostsFromNotion } from '@/services/posts';
import { Post } from '@/types/post';

export default async function PostPage({
  params: { slug },
}: {
  params: { slug: string };
}) {
  const allPosts = await getAllPostsFromNotion();

  const post = allPosts.find((p) => p.slug === slug);
  if (!post) {
    return notFound();
  }

  if (!post.published) {
    return (
      <article className="mx-auto mt-40 text-center">
        <h2 className="mb-4 text-3xl font-bold">Post Not Found</h2>
        <Link href="/blog">
          <span className="mr-2">&larr;</span>
          <span>Go to list page</span>
        </Link>
      </article>
    );
  }

  const relatedPosts: Post[] = allPosts.filter(
    (p) =>
      p.slug !== slug && p.categories.some((v) => post.categories.includes(v))
  );

  const recordMap = await getRecordMap(post.id);

  return (
    <>
      <article className="mt-4 flex flex-col items-center md:mt-20">
        <div className="relative aspect-[3/2] w-[90vw] max-w-[900px]">
          <Image
            src={post.cover}
            alt="cover"
            fill
            sizes="100%"
            style={{ objectFit: 'contain' }}
            priority
          />
        </div>
        <NotionPage post={post} recordMap={recordMap} />
      </article>
      <RelatedPosts posts={relatedPosts} />
    </>
  );
}

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const allPosts = await getAllPostsFromNotion();

  return allPosts.map((post) => ({
    slug: post.slug,
  }));
}

export async function generateMetadata({
  params: { slug },
}: {
  params: { slug: string };
}): Promise<Metadata> {
  const allPosts = await getAllPostsFromNotion();
  const post = allPosts.find((p) => p.slug === slug);

  return post
    ? {
        title: post.title,
        openGraph: {
          images: [
            {
              url: post.cover,
              width: '400',
              height: '300',
            },
          ],
        },
      }
    : {};
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is a problem with route links. Could you show your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.